# Optimize Postgis Query and understanding performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, geocoding, postgis

I have a database on a Digital Ocean Server and it seems a bit slow to me (more than one second sometimes). Postgresql with postgis is running there.

Here are some statistics about the database houses, that actually just stores some apartments:

---

Houses: 190000

```
SELECT count(*) from houses;
```

Houses that have been online for the last 24 h: 58000

```
SELECT count(*) FROM houses 
JOIN (select max(last_seen) as last_ts from houses) as dt 
ON last_seen >= dt.last_ts - interval '24 hour';
```

Houses that are in a specific region and active: 3086

```
 select count(*) from houses 
 where ST_DWithin(geom, ST_MakePoint(52.5277411, 13.4)::geography,30000)
                 (active IS NULL OR active = TRUE)
```

---

**Here is the actual SQL query** that is a bit slow. Slow means it takes sometimes more then one second for one query:

```
SELECT
      *,
      ST_DistanceSphere(geom, ST_MakePoint(52.5277411, 13.4)) as distace
      FROM houses 
      JOIN (select max(last_seen) as last_ts from houses) as dt 
      ON last_seen >= dt.last_ts - interval '24 hour'
      WHERE  
        ST_DWithin(geom, ST_MakePoint(52.5277411, 13.4)::geography,30000)
        AND (active IS NULL OR active = TRUE)
```

What I have tried so far. Remove the join since it is a bit of redundant. Introduce indices.

Here is a query explanation:

[image]

Any Idea how that can be improved? Thanks a lot!

PS: If some data is missing please let me know and I will provide.

Here the same with explain analyze:
[image]

Database Indices:
[image]

Comment: 0) the plan doesn't look *that* bad... 1) add DDL to your question 2) do you have a spatial index on geom? 3) `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` instead of `EXPLAIN`

Comment: Hello yes there is a spatial index on geom. I attached the indices as well as the query with EXPLAIN ANLYZE to the question. Thanks a lot for looking at it.

Comment: BTW: in most cases, it makes little sense to have a boolean column defined as NULLable:`AND (active IS NULL OR active = TRUE)` (you *could* consider a conditional index here)

Comment: Good to know, I understand. To be honest I'm not that familiar with Indices but I don't think this is the bottleneck of the query.

Comment: Is the index on geom a gist index? also: you could add an extra index on the bounding boxes:  `CREATE INDEX ix_pointloc" ON zetable USING gist (box(geom));`

Comment: 4) your rowsize is rather large.

Comment: Added that index. Seems there is not much difference in the execution speed. Not sure if the index on geom ist gist. Is there a way I can find out? What I can see is that geom of the type geometry(Point, 4326). Maybe I need a better Machine. But still, a bit surprised that such queries take that long since. I thought that anything under 10^6 shouldn't be a problem. Maybe a solution would be to create a new table with historical data, but that would make all the queries a bit more complicated.

Comment: Best way to find out the actual definitions is by using `pg_dump --schema-only ...` BTW: you should *always* do an `ANALYZE` after adding/changing an index.

Comment: Thanks - learned something new and yes pg_dump shows that geom is a gist index. What do you think, does it make sense to run every hour or lets say every 10 minutes a query that makes the filtering (active & last_seen < 24h) and put all the new rows to the table and deletes old raws? That table would be used later for the query above

Comment: A guess: You pass ST_DWithin() the (complex) geometry of a house. As ST_DWithin promises to do a bounding-box-check, it should be fast enough. But if appartments are 'small' and 'dense' then the circular boundary of the query has a number of appartments on it. For these cases ST_DWithin may need to perform the full calculation.
So try giving ST_DWithin() the bounding-box of geom, instead of the full geom.

Comment: How do I do that? Not sure if I understand what you mean. So far I have a first solution which materialized the query to the view without the geocoding. My plan was to refresh each hour - maybe with a cron job. But still love to optimize it a bit. As I understand you I have to perform ST_DWithin(BOUNDINGS(geom), ST_MakePoint(52.5277411, 13.4). Will post later the final solution.

Comment: @MichaelRazum: I don't know the BOUNDINGS() function, but it sounds reasonable; Looking at PostGIS I would try ST_Box2D(geom). 
Please note: This 'solution' can only help if your houses.geom is complex, for instance multiple polygons mapping out an appartment. If geom only contains a point, it will make things worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since a lot of people tried to help and gave really good advice I want to post my final solution:
As mentioned in the comments, you should always measure, optimize, repeat. Table size and indices are the key points.

Since I'm not an expert on this topic visualization helped a lot with http://tatiyants.com

```
 Explain (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
 select
  *,
  ST_DistanceSphere(geom, ST_MakePoint(52.5277411, 13.4)) as distace
  FROM houses
  JOIN (select max(last_seen) as last_ts from houses) as dt
  ON last_seen >= dt.last_ts - interval '24 hour'
  WHERE
    ST_DWithin(geom, ST_MakePoint(52.5277411, 13.4)::geography,30000)
    AND (active IS NULL OR active = TRUE);
```

[query visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on5as.png)

That helped for the basic understanding. Since I was already using indices, there was not that much optimization possible. In my case it was ok to get a bit delayed results. I introduce materialized view which stores a part of the query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mathouses
 select
  *,
  FROM houses
  JOIN (select max(last_seen) as last_ts from houses) as dt
  ON last_seen >= dt.last_ts - interval '24 hour'
  WHERE (active IS NULL OR active = TRUE);
```

Then added an Index on that view. And added a simple shell script that is called every hour by cron:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -u <myuser>-Hi -- psql -d <db> -c 'refresh materialized view mathouses;'
```

My final result:

```
 Explain (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
 select
  *,
  ST_DistanceSphere(geom, ST_MakePoint(52.5277411, 13.4)) as distace
  FROM mathouses
  WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, ST_MakePoint(52.5277411, 13.4)::geography,30000);
```

[query visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeEX9.png)

Pretty happy with the solution. It's a factor 3x or even more faster right now. To go further the next logical step would be to look at the hardware or optimize the postgresql settings.